# python: find the last appearance of a word (of a list of words) in a text

Tags: python, list, loops

given a list of stop words and a string:

```
list_stop_words = ['for', 'the', 'with']
mystring = 'this is the car for the girl with the long nice red hair'
```

I would like to get the text starting from the end up to the first stop word of the list.

expected result 'the long nice red hair'

I tried with several for loops but it is super cumbersome there should be a straight way, probably even a one liner.

my super verbose solution:

```
list_stop_words = ['for', 'the', 'with']
mystring = 'this is the car for the girl with the long nice red hair'

reversed_sentence =mystring.split()[::-1]
for i,word in enumerate(reversed_sentence):
    if word in list_stop_words:
        position = i
        words = reversed_sentence[0:i+1]
        print(' '.join(words[::-1]))
        break
for word in mastering[::-1]:
```

Any suggestion for a better approach?

EDIT AFTER THE ANSWER (SEE BELLOW)
[image]

Comment: I notice you tagged the question as `list-comprehension`. Do you in fact understand what list comprehensions are and how to use them? Does https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ help?

Comment: yes I do, but often times its not straight forward

Comment: I started trying to write a detailed answer, before noticing that you didn't actually want to drop all the stop words out. In the future, please explicitly state your exact desired output for the given example input. I removed the `list-comprehension` tag because it would be difficult to impossible to use those productively for this task.

Comment: Thanks @KarlKnechtel. Nevertheless I dont understand your point since the answer I marked as ok (see bellow) actually is a list comprehension. I also EDITed the question to include the answer with the timeit comparisons.

Comment: It seemed like you hoped to find a comprehension that would directly generate the desired list. This one generates *indices of stop words* by iterating over the stop words, so that one can be selected and used for a slice. Actually rather clever.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you are technically right, its not a pure list comprehension but its a one-liner. And yes, pretty clever ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
mystring[max([mystring.rfind(stop_word) for stop_word in list_stop_words]):]
```

basically you find the last occurence of each word with `rfind` then you find the last from all the words with max then you slice it out

Comment: this is really good: